# using href to reference folders back from the root folder

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a page to allow the user to open documents stored on the web server that they have earlier uploaded.  However, the folder in which they are stored is one folder back from the root folder and I don't know to reference it.  The code I have at the moment will pick up files from the root folder but not any further back :

```
documents += "<tr><td><a class='LinkGreen' href='../../../" + msg.d[i].FileLocation + msg.d[i].DocumentName + "'>" + msg.d[i].DocumentName + "<a/></td></tr>";
```

Is it possible to make reference to folders that are parents of the root folder in a href link?

Comment: I think this is possible only if your host allows/enables it, and with absolute paths. From my own experience with my own host. This question *might* be better placed on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), though. But I'm not voting to close since I'm unsure, and I think the answers would be useful here, too.

Comment: as david says, you cannot do it just like that. if you know the absolute path, then you could always use that. which language / platform?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access documents outside of your webserver's root. If you want to do this, you either have to write a script that allows to download files outside of it or create a symlink in the document root linking outside of it.

Comment: Or make a server call that uses File IO on the server (also assuming appropriate permissions) to open and send that file back to the client.